# Notification Not Appearing Android

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, android-glide

I am currently trying to implement push notifications for my android app with FCM, However when I send a notification it doesn't appear on the phone. I know for sure that the app received the message since it appears in the logcat, but the notification itself doesn't appear and i'm not sure where I went wrong. I got an error from Glide but I tried again without the LargeIcon and the `.notify` line outside of the glide line and still nothing appeared. Any help is appreciated :)

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Uri soundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Spannable sb = new SpannableString("Switcheroo");
        sb.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 0, 10, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app_icon_waves_round)
                .setContentTitle(sb)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).asBitmap().load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.music_placeholder).into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(resource);
                notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
            }
        });
```

LogCat:

```
 D/PAYLOAD: Message data payload: {image=https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/WNUBiv2P6YSklHn9eA5nlg/1000x1000bb.jpeg, message=Barbecu sent you his "Run The Jewels" Playlist}
 W/Glide: Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from Android 8.0 (API level 26), notifications won't show unless you provide [`NotificationChannel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel) as a second argument to the `NotificationCompat.Builder` constructor.

So, to solve that, create a `NotificationChannel` for API 26+

```
// Notification channels are only available in OREO and higher.
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

    NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel
            ("PRIMARY_CHANNEL_ID",
                    "Service",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

    notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
    notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
    notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
    notificationChannel.setDescription("Description");

    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
}
```

use the channel ID "PRIMARY_CHANNEL_ID" as a second argument to the `NotificationCompat.Builder` constructor.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "PRIMARY_CHANNEL_ID")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app_icon_waves_round)
            .setContentTitle(sb)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use Glide4 in your app. you have to make class like this.

```
import android.content.Context;

import com.bumptech.glide.GlideBuilder;
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule;
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule;

@GlideModule
public final class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {
    @Override
    public void applyOptions(Context context, GlideBuilder builder) {

    }
}
```

check [this](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/generatedapi.html). happy coding!